# JSONPowerDB query is giving me an error for 'REMOVE'

Tags: json, database

The request I gave was the same way as stated in the docs for JPDB and I got this error:

> jsonStr was empty / Syntax Error/ Request couldn't be processed - java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> Refer https://login2explore.com/jpdb/docs.html for help.

I tried this query

```json
{
"token": "90931604|-31949302181346949|90960211",
        "cmd": "REMOVE",
        "dbName": "Student",
        "rel": "student-rel",
"record": 1,
    "jsonStr":
        {}
}
```

and this is the url:
`http://api.login2explore.com:5577/api/iml/`

Answer (score 0):

The error is with your api url. REMOVE cmd works with http://api.login2explore.com:5577/api/iml/set .
That should fix your issue